# Add multiple File from find command to single mail using UNIX

Tags: shell, unix

by using the below find Command i have found 3 file that are less than 30 min

```
find /pathA -type f  -mmin -30 -print0
```

but i want to send all the 3 files in one mail with 3 attachment.I tried below code.it works for single file but for multi files it fails. please help me .

```
echo "hi" | mail -s "files older less than 30 min" -a "$(find /pathA -type f  -mmin -30 -print0)" abcd@email.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add separate `-a` option for each file. Try this: it accumulates an array to hold all the mail options:

```
mail_opts=( -s "files older less than 30 min" )
while read -d "" -r file; do
    mail_opts+=( -a "$file" )
done < <(find /pathA -type f  -mmin -30 -print0)
echo "message body" | mail "${mail_opts[@]}" abcd@email.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this;

```
find /pathA -type f  -mmin -30 -exec bash -c 'uuencode {} {}'  \; | mail -s "files older less than 30 min"  abcd@email.com
```